# increase png resolution when using saveHTML() {animation} in R

Tags: r, animation, png, resolution, figures

I am in need of a way to increase the resolution of the png files created by saveHTML().

Here is a dummy script of what I am trying to do where in reality plot() is a number of nested loops:

```
x<-y<-rep(1,10)
saveHTML( for (i in 1:10){
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10))
plot(x[i],y[i])
}
,ani.dev="png",img.name="test",htmlfile="test")
```

A few things I have tried:
1) increase the animation size using ani.options(ani.height,ani.width) but I only get a larger grainy image.
2) call png() device inside the saveHTML expression and set the resolution there, but ultimately I dont get any figures.
3) call a new windows() device for plotting and setting the window size, but again this does not increase the resolution.

The most straight forward work-around that I came across is to create hi-res pngs and animate using ffmpeg. But I am not ready to re-work my script just yet.

Has anyone found a way to increase png resolution inside the saveHTML() function?

Comment: What do you mean "larger grainy image"? I get exactly what I'd expect, a larger png, just as if I'd called `png` with that width and height. Is your `png` driver broken? Can you point us to screenshots?

Comment: @Spacedman As you describe I get the larger (width x height) image as if I called the png driver directly. But I do not get an increase in resolution. So what results is a dimensional larger image that is pixelated to where you can hardly read the figure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `ani.dev="png"`, you can pass `ani.dev = function(...){png(res=75*grain,...)}`, where `grain` is some number > 1. If you specify the options `ani.height` and/or `ani.width` and multiply these values by the same factor `grain`, then you effectively increase the pixel resolution of the output by this factor.

N.B.: the default resolution `75` above might be machine dependent, I did not see it documented.